# listview Header check-box

Tags: c#, listview

I'm having a windows form which contains listview control , 
where `listView1.View = View.Details;` and `listView1.CheckBoxes = true;`

then added a column with HeaderName as "FileName".

```
listView1.Columns.Add("File Name", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Here I would like to have check box in the Header of listview , ie FileName.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.
andy

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ListView header with a checkbox is not part of the standard ListView functionality. You'll need to customise the renderering to do this:

```
    listview.OwnerDraw = true


    private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw your custom checkbox control here
    }

    private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }

    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
```

You'll also have to add some click handlers for the header and manage the state of your checkboxes yourself.

Comment: @Andy: If this was the answer to your question, would you consider marking as the answer?

Comment: but where is the complete one?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my answer in C# which also accounts for the click event and also C# event handling from the VB.NET

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e) 
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == 0))
    {
        CheckBox cck = new CheckBox();
        // With...
        Text = "";
        Visible = true;
        listView1.SuspendLayout();
        e.DrawBackground();
        cck.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        cck.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        cck.SetBounds(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, cck.GetPreferredSize(new Size(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height)).Width, cck.GetPreferredSize(new Size(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height)).Width);
        cck.Size = new Size((cck.GetPreferredSize(new Size((e.Bounds.Width - 1), e.Bounds.Height)).Width + 1), e.Bounds.Height);
        cck.Location = new Point(3, 0);
        listView1.Controls.Add(cck);
        cck.Show();
        cck.BringToFront();
        e.DrawText((TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left));
        cck.Click += new EventHandler(Bink);
        listView1.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void Bink(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox test = sender as CheckBox;

    for (int i=0;i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {     
        listView1.Items[i].Checked = test.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a little bit to your code: 'CheckState state = CheckState.Unchecked; cck.CheckState = state; state = test.CheckState;' Every time the listview was redrawn it refreshed the checkbox and caused it to draw cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I did it! Thanks Matt!

```
'Sorry guys I still love Visual Basic... assuming LV here is a List View control

Private Sub LV_DrawColumnHeader(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles LV.DrawColumnHeader
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim cck As New CheckBox With {.Text = "", .Visible = True}
        LV.SuspendLayout() : e.DrawBackground()
        cck.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        cck.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        cck.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CheckboxBackground
        cck.SetBounds(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, _
          cck.GetPreferredSize(New Size(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height)).Width, _
          cck.GetPreferredSize(New Size(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height)).Width)
        cck.Size = New Size(cck.GetPreferredSize(New Size(e.Bounds.Width - 1, e.Bounds.Height)).Width + 1, e.Bounds.Height)
        cck.Location = New Point(3, 0)
        LV.Controls.Add(cck)
        cck.Show()
        cck.BringToFront()
        e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.Left)
        LV.ResumeLayout(True)
    Else
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LV_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles LV.DrawItem
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub LV_DrawSubItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles LV.DrawSubItem
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub
```

In my code above, I just want to draw a checkbox at first column header... That is, e.ColumnIndex = 0.
In order to make the checkbox respond properly to user's click, we need to add handler with this piece of code.

```
'this line should be added before LV.ResumeLayout()
AddHandler cck.CheckedChanged, AddressOf theCheckboxInHeader_CheckChanged

'then add this procedure elsewhere in the file.
Private Sub theCheckboxInHeader_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Enter code here
End Sub
```

Due to stackoverflow.com policy, new users (such as me) are forbidden to post images... so I cannot post my screenshot here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfiFl.png

Btw... does stackoverflow.com code highlighting javascript only supports C#?

Comment: Hi Ryan Im very keen to know how you had the listview group name on the same line of text , I mean  "AlphaMart---------------" and "IndoMart--------------------", as in my case using visual studio 2008 it comes beneath the text  not on the same line . could you please advise on this.

Answer (score 1):

This will work more efficiently than the above written solutions,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
bool clicked = false;
CheckBoxState state;
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col1", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col2", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col3", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col4", 150);
        listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Clickable;
        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        listView1.OwnerDraw = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            listView1.Items.Add("Value " + i);
    }

    private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!clicked)
        {
            clicked = true;
            state    = CheckBoxState.CheckedPressed;

            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.Checked = true;
            }

            Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            clicked = false;
            state = CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
            Invalidate();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.Checked = false;
            }
        }           
    }

    private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding;
        e.DrawBackground();
        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle.Location, state);
        e.DrawText(flags);
    }

    private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }

    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
}
```